# TCL Program that Compare String

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to create a program that the First and last characters are compared,  Second and second to the last are compared,  Third and third to the last are compared, and so on, and if any of these characters match, the two will be converted to the uppercase of that character.

Example:

Please enter a text: Hello Philippines
finals: HEllo PhIlippinEs

I can't create any piece of code, I'm stuck with

```
puts "Please enter text:"
set myText [gets stdin]

string index $myText 4
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This procedure will also capitalize the first `i` in Phillipines because it's equidistant from the start and the end of the string.

```
proc compare_chars {str} {
    set letters [split $str ""]
    for {set i [expr {[llength $letters] / 2}]} {$i >= 0} {incr i -1} {
        set a [lindex $letters $i]
        set b [lindex $letters end-$i]
        if {$a eq $b} {
            lset letters $i [set L [string toupper $a]]
            lset letters end-$i $L
        }
    }
    join $letters ""
}
puts [compare_chars "Hello Phillipines"]
# outputs =>  HEllo PhIllipinEs
```

Comment: its good but my tCL does not recognize the lset command and lreverse, I am using the older version which is version 8.3

Comment: @Dhenn, in this case, you can implement lset like this: `proc lset {varname index value} {upvar 1 $varname var; set var [lreplace $var $index $index $value]}`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to code this is to use `foreach` over the split-up characters. (It's formally not the most efficient, but it's very easy to code correctly.)

```
puts "Please enter text:"
set myText [gets stdin]

set chars [split $myText ""]
set idx 0
foreach a $chars b [lreverse $chars] {
    if {[string equals -nocase $a $b]} {
        lset chars $idx [string toupper $a]
    }
    incr idx
}
set output [join $chars ""]

puts $output
```

Note that the `foreach` is iterating over a copy of the list; there are no problems with concurrent modification. In fact, the only vaguely-tricky part from a coding perspective is actually that we need to keep track of the index to modify, in the `idx` variable above.

---

With Tcl 8.6 you could write:

```
set chars [split $myText ""]
set output [join [lmap a $chars b [lreverse $chars] {
    expr {[string equals -nocase $a $b] ? [string toupper $a] : $a}
}] ""]
```

That does depend on having the new `lmap` command though.

---

If you're really stuck with 8.3 (it's **unsupported** and has been so for years, so you should be prioritizing upgrading to something more recent) then try this:

```
set chars [split $myText ""]
set idx [llength $chars]
set output {}
foreach ch $chars {
    if {[string equals -nocase $ch [lindex $chars [incr idx -1]]]} {
        append output [string toupper $ch]
    } else {
        append output [string tolower $ch]
    }
}
```

All the features this uses were present in 8.3 (though some were considerably slower than in later versions).

Comment: Hi thanks! but my tCL does not recognize the lset command and lreverse, I am using the older version which is version 8.3

Comment: 8.3???  **Upgrade!**  8.3 has not been supported at all for years (unless you've been able to persuade someone to do so on a commercial basis) and 8.4 is about to move into the same position (its final patch release —  8.4.20 — is likely to be within the next month).

Comment: @Dhenn, lreverse can be implemented like `proc lreverse {a_list} {set rev [list]; for {set i [expr {[llength $a_list] - 1}]} {$i >= 0} {incr i -1} {lappend rev [lindex $a_list $i]}; return $rev}`